# SQL Selecting True or false with joins and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how to get back a true/false value in my query. Here is what I'm trying but it is not working.

```
SELECT TOP 10
    t1.Id as UserId,
    CASE WHEN (t2.UserId = t1.Id AND t2.ItemId = 1) THEN CAST(1 as BIT) ELSE cast(0 as BIT) END as IsFavourite,

    FROM Users t1
    INNER JOIN UserFavorite t2 ON t1.Id = t2.UserId

GROUP BY t1.Id
```

The error that I get is:

> invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I understand that I need to have something in the group by section for this to work, but I don't understand what. Also the query has been simplified as it joins multiple tables.

Just to clarify, Favorites tables basically has Id, UserId, ItemId. So if there is a combination of User and Item it means it was Favorited.

Comment: add t2.ItemId in the group by ... but really we need data and expected output to suggest a proper answer

Comment: Why are you grouping by `t1.Id` if you are not using any aggregation in your query?

Comment: @CodingYoshi because its a simplified query for the point of asking how to solve the problem.

Comment: You do not need to use `group by`. If you want a good answer and help with something, explain what you want to do. Showing us how you are doing it, and then telling us that it is not really how you are doing it, is not helpful. You do not need `group by` in your case (even if it works and gives you the correct results, it makes no sense).

Comment: @CodingYoshi you are too stuck on the little things. The point was how do I make it work with group by regardless of whether or not I need in the query. Don't make things bigger then they are, just causes drama for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 10
t1.Id as UserId,
(CASE WHEN   t2.ItemId = 1 THEN CAST(1 as BIT) ELSE 
cast(0 as BIT) END) as IsFavourite,
FROM Users t1
INNER JOIN UserFavorite t2 ON t1.Id = t2.UserId
GROUP BY t1.Id,t2.ItemId
```

Comment: So I just need to individually list all the columns used in the case statement. I arrived at that conclusion, but I wasn't sure if it is the correct way. It felt, hacky. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM
(
    SELECT
               t1.Id as UserId
            ,  CASE 
                 WHEN (t2.UserId = t1.Id AND t2.ItemId = 1) 
                 THEN CAST(1 as BIT) 
                 ELSE cast(0 as BIT) END as IsFavourite
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
    FROM Users t1
    INNER JOIN UserFavorite t2 ON t1.Id = t2.UserId
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```